# Accessing a variable within a store in ExtJs 6 MVC

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, geoext3

I wanted to access a variable created within a store but I couldn't access. Below is the part of the code.

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.store.TreeStore', {
        extend: 'GeoExt.data.store.LayersTree',
        alias: 'store.layer_tree',
        init: function(app) {
            ....

            this.ol_map = new ol.Map({
                layers: [group, layer3, layer4],
                view: new ol.View({
                    center: [0, 0],
                    zoom: 2
                })
            });

        },
        layerGroup: this.ol_map.getLayerGroup()
    });
```

I want to access `ol_map` within the store in `layerGroup`.

Comment: Which var you want to access explain it

Comment: I want to access ol_map. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your store init function is executed after the layerGroup definition.

To fix:

```
    init: function(app) {
        ....

        this.ol_map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [group, layer3, layer4],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2
            })
        });
        this.layerGroup = this.ol_map.getLayerGroup()

    },
```

Comment: Unfortunately,  GeoExt plugin is complaining that `layerGroup` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, `layerGroup` is not `undefined` but `null`. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLayers' of null`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I can add a function for the property as shown below.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.TreeStore', {
    extend: 'GeoExt.data.store.LayersTree',
    alias: 'store.layer_tree',
    layerGroup: (function() {
        ....

        this.ol_map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [group, layer3, layer4],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2
            })
        });
        return this.ol_map.getLayerGroup()

    }) ()
});
```

Comment: This is another variation of Alexander's solution. The problem is that the 'this' context in the original problem isn't the object - it's the scope that the Ext.define is being called in (probably the global scope).

When you put the population of the ``ol_map`` variable into a function, the ``this`` context is different - normally it's the ExtJS object (unless there are some silly games being played)

Comment: The problem with Alexander's solution is `layerGroup` is still null. So what is the correct context that should be used to access `layerGroup` property?

Comment: Is the ``init`` method being called? I don't know the GeoExt library, so I can't be sure - but regular ExtJS stores do not have an ``init`` method.

Comment: It is not called. That could be the reason why Alexander's solution didn't work for me.

Comment: It would certainly be a part of the problem... ;)

Comment: Well, I didn't know that the OP did not even check the basic "is a function executed" before asking...